# Nextcloud server

Tags: router, dns, port-forwarding, nextcloud

I have a nextcloud server (Nextcloud VM installed within a Kubuntu 18.04 host) that has unexpectedly stopped accepting external connections.

Pinging from an external IP works just fine so I don't think this is an DNS issue. I can access the server from the internal IP as well. But from an external IP address I get the error: "This site can't be reached. example.com unexpectedly closed the connection" when using Chrome.

I confirmed that ports 443 and 80 are forwarded using `yougetsignal.com` and my router is forwarding those ports to the server. My ip address is not static so I am using dyndns, but I have updated the IP address in the dyndns system manually without resolution to the problem.

This is my first server and I have run out of troubleshooting ideas. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you ckecked fail2ban status

Answer (score 1):

The error message is referring to example.com

I am guessing that the trusted_domains setting in your config.php is configured wrong.

'trusted_domains' =>
[
'demo.example.org',
'otherdomain.example.org',
'10.111.112.113',
'[2001:db8::1]'
],

But it could also be your httpd (Apache/NGinX) configuration is at fault.

Please make sure that you include the dyndns domain in your trusted_domains and httpd server configuration. Usually the dyndns domain name is not your primary hostname, hence special care should be taken.